# Multi threading with a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method with a ConcurrentHashMap with the following behavior.

1. Read no lock
2. Write lock
3. prior to writing,

   1. read to see if record exist,
   2. if it still doesn't exist, save to database and add record to map.
   3. if record exist from previous write, just return record.

My thoughts.

```
private Object lock1 = new Object();

private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> productMap;

private Object getProductMap(String name) {

    if (productMap.isEmpty()) {
        productMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    if (productMap.containsKey(name)) {
        return productMap.get(name);
    }

    synchronized (lock1) {
        if (productMap.containsKey(name)) {
            return productMap.get(name);
        } else {
            Product product = new Product(name);
            session.save(product);
            productMap.putIfAbsent(name, product);
        }
    }

}
```

Could someone help me to understand if this is a correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

There are several bugs here.

- If `productMap` isn't guaranteed to be initialized, you will get an `NPE` in your first statement to this method.
- The method isn't guaranteed to return anything if the map is empty.
- The method doesn't return on all paths.
- The method is both poorly named and unnecessary; you're trying to emulate [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) which half accomplishes your goal.
- You also don't need to do any synchronization; `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe for your purposes.

If I were to rewrite this, I'd do a few things differently:

- Eagerly instantiate the `ConcurrentHashMap`
- Bind it to `ConcurrentMap` instead of the concrete class (so `ConcurrentMap<String, Product> productMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`)
- Rename the method to `putIfMissing` and delegate to `putIfAbsent`, with some logic to return the same record I want to add if the result is `null`.  The above **absolutely depends on** `Product` having a well-defined `equals` and `hashCode` method, such that `new Product(name)` will produce objects with the same values for `equals` and `hashCode` if provided the same `name`.
- Use an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to avoid any NPEs with the result of `putIfAbsent`, and to provide easier to digest code.

A snippet of the above:

```
public Product putIfMissing(String key) {
    Product product = new Product(key);
    Optional<Product> result =
         Optional.ofNullable(productMap.putIfAbsent(key, product));
    session.save(result.orElse(product));
    return result.orElse(product);
}
```

Comment: First I'd like to say thank you, but I have a couple questions to be sure I fully understand the logic. 1. If instantiating Product every time putIfMissing is called, will it create unnecessary garbage collection? I will call this method millions of times in a very short period of time, would that create any unnecessary garbage collection? 2. If it's in fact a new product, would the product value be updated with the persistent object so that it's available to all objects calling putIfMissing? 3. what exactly is being passed into session.save when the product already exist? Thanks